# What is the most elegant / pythonic way of introducing large integer constants?

Tags: python, coding-style, pep8

I have a need to introduce large integer constants (primes for Diffie-Hellman key exchange)

What is the most pythonic / pretty way of doing so in a PEP8 compliant manner? Preferably with no backslashes.

My current approach is something like:

```
N = '''FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF C90FDAA2 2168C234 C4C6628B 80DC1CD1
       29024E08 8A67CC74 020BBEA6 3B139B22 514A0879 8E3404DD
       EF9519B3 CD3A431B 302B0A6D F25F1437 4FE1356D 6D51C245
       E485B576 625E7EC6 F44C42E9 A637ED6B 0BFF5CB6 F406B7ED
       EE386BFB 5A899FA5 AE9F2411 7C4B1FE6 49286651 ECE65381
       FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF'''
PRIME = int('0x{0}'.format(N.replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '')), 16)
```

not very pretty, but prettier than:

```
PRIME = 179769313486231590770839156793787453197860296048756011706444423684197180216158519368947833795864925541502180565485980503646440548199239100050792877003355816639229553136239076508735759914822574862575007425302077447712589550957937778424442426617334727629299387668709205606050270810842907692932019128194467627007L
```

**EDIT**:

Changed to `PRIME = int(re.sub('\s+', '', N), 16)`

Comment: `0xffffffffffffffffc90fdaa22168c234c4c6628b80dc1cd129024e088a67cc74020bbea63b139b22514a08798e3404ddef9519b3cd3a431b302b0a6df25f14374fe1356d6d51c245e485b576625e7ec6f44c42e9a637ed6b0bff5cb6f406b7edee386bfb5a899fa5ae9f24117c4b1fe649286651ece65381ffffffffffffffff`(`L`) would be a way, but your `N` is much prettier.

Comment: You could consider how someone viewing your source code might use the constant. They are not going to verify in their heads that it is prime, no matter how you write it. So probably, the only manner in which they will ever actually "read" it is to copy it into some other code, or into Mathematica to verify its properties, or whatever. Perhaps, then, you should optimize for that use-case. That is, use your un-pretty solution `PRIME = 1797...`. Remember that after correctness the primary purpose of source code is not to be pretty, it is to be useful to readers.

Comment: Aside from anything else, though, I prefer `''.join(N.split())` to `N.replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '')`

Comment: I would put that value into a text file and read it with python. Problem solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite frankly what you have is pretty decent.  The only obvious change would be your final conversion: you can drop the `"0x{0}".format` bit and just pass the replaced string as you give `int` the base 16.

Other than that, you could always hide it a function:

```
def PrimeInt(string):
    return int(string.replace('\n','').replace(' ',''), 16)

PRIME = PrimeInt("""
        FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF C90FDAA2 2168C234 C4C6628B 80DC1CD1
        29024E08 8A67CC74 020BBEA6 3B139B22 514A0879 8E3404DD
        EF9519B3 CD3A431B 302B0A6D F25F1437 4FE1356D 6D51C245
        E485B576 625E7EC6 F44C42E9 A637ED6B 0BFF5CB6 F406B7ED
        EE386BFB 5A899FA5 AE9F2411 7C4B1FE6 49286651 ECE65381
        FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF
        ''')
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [PEP 8 Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds)

> But most importantly: know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes the
>   style guide just doesn't apply. When in doubt, use your best judgment.
>   Look at other examples and decide what looks best. And don't hesitate
>   to ask!

So leave the constant as-is, as its more readable than any other un-obvious hacks

And most importantly `Readability counts.`

Nothing is above the the core principles of Python

> but there MUST be a more elegant way of doing PRIME =
>   int('0x{0}'.format(N.replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '')), 16)...

If you insist

```
PRIME=long('17976931348623159077083915679378745319786029604875601'
          '17064444236841971802161585193689478337958649255415021805654859805'
          '03646440548199239100050792877003355816639229553136239076508735759'
          '91482257486257500742530207744771258955095793777842444242661733472'
          '7629299387668709205606050270810842907692932019128194467627007L')
```

Comment: +1 - but there MUST be a more elegant way of doing `PRIME = int('0x{0}'.format(N.replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '')), 16)`...

Comment: Actually, found it myself `int(re.sub('\s+', '', N), 16)`

Comment: That is *not* more elegant. :/

Comment: Incidentally, my comment was directed at Abhijit's `PRIME=long...`, not the `re.sub`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to look nice maybe you can convert from a string to an integer. Its probably not best practice though, as I've never actually seen it used in practice, but I think its a bit more clear than the original method because of the limited conversions

```
number = (
    "179769313486231590770839156793787453197860296048756011"
    "706444423684197180216158519368947833795864925541502180"
    "565485980503646440548199239100050792877003355816639229"
    "553136239076508735759914822574862575007425302077447712"
    "589550957937778424442426617334727629299387668709205606"
    "050270810842907692932019128194467627007"
)
number = int(number)
179769313486231590770839156793787453197860296048756011706444423684197180216158519368947833795864925541502180565485980503646440548199239100050792877003355816639229553136239076508735759914822574862575007425302077447712589550957937778424442426617334727629299387668709205606050270810842907692932019128194467627007L
```

Comment: You could also just put `int` at the original assignment.